# Беспроводная сеть недоступна после установки Linux Mint 20.1

Tags: сеть, linux-mint, ос

Установила Linux Mint 20.1 в качестве второй ОС и обнаружила, что wifi соединения нет. Прочитала, что нет необходимых драйверов, но где их найти для моего сетевого контроллера, так и не разобралась.
Вдруг кто-то сталкивался, подскажите пожалуйста.

Мой сетевой контроллер:

01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась. Помогли следующие команды:

Сделайте резервную копию, чтобы вы могли ее восстановить:

sudo cp -r /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/ ~/

Перезапись прошивки:

sudo wget http://www.killernetworking.com/support/K1535_Debian/board.bin -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin

sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1/firmware-6.bin_WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00132-QCARMSWP-1 -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin

sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin

После перезагрузки компьютера появились доступные сети и я подключилась к wi-fi, и я удалила резервную копию:

sudo rm -rf ~/QCA6174/